# How to access member variables across member functions in C++

Tags: c++, qt

> **I'm completely new to C++.**

In Java:

```
class MyClass {

    public String memberVar;

    public MyClass(String memberVar) {
        memberVar = memberVar;
    }

    void myMethod() {
        system.out.println(memberVar);
    }

    void anotherMethod() {
        system.out.println(memberVar);
    }
}
```

...

```
class CallMyClass {
    CallMyClass() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myMethod();
        myClass.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

In C++:

**myclass.h**

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        QString memberVar;

        MyClass(QString memberVar);

        void myMethod();
        void anotherMethod();
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString memberVar)
{
    MyClass::memberVar = memberVar;
}
```

to access `memberVar` in a method inside `MyClass` in **myclass.cpp**, it seems I always have to come up with a new instance of `MyClass`.

```
MyClass::myMethod() {
    MyClass myClass("Only var");
    qDebug() << myClass.memberVar;
}

MyClass::anotherMethod() {
    MyClass myClass("Only var");
    qDebug() << myClass.memberVar;
}
```

Can I initialize an object once instance and use it accross the various methods within a particular calling class, like in Java?

Comment: I don't suppose you just tried: `qtDebug() << memberVar;`

Comment: actually for this particular question it is just as it is in java. Any (non-static) member method has an implicit `this` parameter. And you access a member variable either via `this->memberVar` or simply by `memberVar`. .... other from that you need to learn C++ from scratch and dont try to write code in C++ as you would do it in java, because this will end up in a big mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it should probably look like

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString memberVar) : memberVar(memberVar)
{}

void MyClass::myMethod() {
    qDebug() << memberVar;
}

void MyClass::anotherMethod() {
    qDebug() << memberVar;
}
```

We use a member initializer list to construct the member variable once. Writing it as we would in Java will call the default constructor of `memberVar` first, and then we will assign to it in the body of our c'tor. That can seriously under-preform for complex types.

Comment: I don't like the `: memberVar(memberVar)` syntax. I don't know how the newer standards interpret that construct, but in C++03 it was a bug - both `memberVar`s resolved to `this->memberVar`. As a result, I always avoid naming the parameters in the constructor identical to the data members.

Comment: @Leon, It's fine in [C++03 as well](https://godbolt.org/g/xN6aFn). It admit I don't care for it myself, but it is legal. It's ambiguous only *inside* the c'tor body. Anyway, I tried to keep it as close to the OP's example. Only changing what's required for the code to do what they expect.

Comment: Maybe it was just a problem with the compiler that we used at the time.

Answer (score 1):

you have named parameter to constructor same as class member: memberVar, and putting MyClass::memberVar would work fine if it was static, you want to name parameter as something else for clarity, say 'BLA' then the constructor would look like:

    `MyClass::MyClass(QString BLA) {
        memberVar = BLA; // now memberVar refers to the instance member 
    }`

and anotherMethod would look like this:

```
MyClass::anotherMethod() {      
    qDebug() << memberVar;  // memberVar is now instance variable that was initialized in constructor
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the return type

Answer (score 0):

in myclass.h

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        QString memberVar;

        MyClass(QString memberVar);

        void myMethod();
        void anotherMethod();
};
```

memberVar is a public variable

you can use it in all of your methods inside MyCall as well as other classes (it's public after all)

This would be valid.

```
void MyClass::myMethod() {
    qDebug() << memberVar;
}
```

You only need the scope operator "::" when there is ambiguity as to which variable you are referring.

In your constructor for MyClass you are creating a local variable with the same name as the class variable. Now there is ambiguity. The same happens in your Java program above in this part

```
class MyClass {

    public String memberVar;

    public MyClass(String memberVar) {
        memberVar = memberVar;
    }
...
}
```

Java may take care of this situation cleanly, but it is still ambiguous. Were you intending to try to set memberVar equal to itself?

You can alleviate the ambiguity 2 ways.

First, using the *this* keyword.
I believe this works in Java and C++

Java

```
class MyClass {

    public String memberVar;

    public MyClass(String memberVar) {
        this.memberVar = memberVar;
    }
    ...
}
```

C++

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString memberVar)
{
    MyClass::memberVar = memberVar;
}
```

or

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString memberVar)
{
    this->memberVar = memberVar;
}
```

Second, is the way I prefer. simply use different variable names so the ambiguity is not possible.

```
MyClass(QString myMemberVar)
{
    memberVar = myMemberVar;
}
```

Bear in mind this will only work if you have the functions declared inside a class, so that you will not need to put "MyClass::" before everything that is only defined inside a different scope.

Here is how I would write myclass.cpp

```
class MyClass {

    MyClass(QString myMemberVar)
    {
        memberVar = myMemberVar;
    }
};
```

notice how the class keyword allows you to use all functions and variables of the myclass header without having to use the scope operator ::